# Keep WebSocket connection in current page alive when command button action is invoked

Tags: jsf, websocket, commandbutton

I've created a WebSocket in a JSF application. It works fine, but when I invoke a JSF bean action using `<h:commandButton action="#{bean.something}">`, then it restarts the WebSocket connection.

Is there any way to implement this 2 types of connections without interrupting each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSF `<h:commandButton>` component generates a HTML `<input type="submit">` element which performs by default a **synchronous** form submit which has as consequence a full page reload and thus a full change of the HTML document.

This is fully expected behavior. You want an **asynchronous** (ajax) form submit instead. This way the HTML document remains the same. In order to achieve that, just nest a `<f:ajax>` inside the `<h:commandButton>`.

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```